# How do I resize each of the multiple images so that each fills up the target frame (expand or contract)?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have multiple images that at various times I need to replace a **target** image for a SKSpriteNode.

Each of these multiple images has a different size.

The **target** SKSpriteNode has a **fixed frame** that I want to stay fixed.

This **target** is created via:

```
myTarget = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: “target”)

myTarget.size = CGSize(…)
myTarget.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: myTarget.size)
```

**How do I resize each of the multiple images so that each fills up the target frame (expand or contract)?**

Pretend the target is a shoebox and each image is a balloon that expands or contracts to fill the shoebox.

I have tried the following that fails, that is, it changes the size of the target to fit the new image .. in short, it does the exact opposite of what I want.

```
let newTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: newImage)
let changeImgAction = SKAction.setTexture(newTexture, resize: true)
myTarget.run(changeImgAction)
```

Again, keep frame of myTarget fixed and change size of newTexture to fit the above frame ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417743-settexture):

> resize: If true, the sprite is resized to match the new texture. Otherwise, the size of the sprite is unchanged.

So, if I understood your question correctly, you simply don't set `resize` to `true`:

```
let newTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: newImage)
let changeImgAction = SKAction.setTexture(newTexture)
myTarget.run(changeImgAction)
```

Comment: Regretfully that doesn’t work. I wish you were right. With your approach, all images would have to be of same size to begin with  by using some image manipulation app.

Comment: … and then you would just use = **myTarget.texture = newTexture**

Comment: Are you sure about that? Because before posting, I tested it on a sample project I made, using images of different sizes from Assets folder, and they were in fact resized accordingly to the sprite size I set. Can you post a sample project maybe, so I can check this better in your code?

Comment: Also, the issue you are facing is that some textures don't fill the node size? Like they are smaller? If so, could be a problem about some images having wider clear backgrounds.

Comment: You are spot on. Your way works perfectly. I can change the selected image that will expand or contact to the size of the target Sprite. BINGO

Comment: NOT related to Sprites, but rather to the Swift Compiler. Got some genius at the Apple Developer Site to explain why   -(a/2 - b) won’t compile, but -(a/2.0 - b) will [where a + b are Doubles]

Thank you oneshot for making your solution easier than the above Double puzzle.

Comment: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted if it solved your issue, might come handy for others as well.